# Heroku give port to html javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to get the server port from the index.html but I can't.

I have a web.js:

```
var PeerServer = require("peer").PeerServer;
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

console.log("PORT IS: " + port);

var server = new PeerServer({
    port: port
});
```

and a js into my index.html:

```
...  
var peer = new Peer({
    host: window.location.hostname,
    port: 5000,
    debug: 3
});
...
```

I try to give the port from web.js to my html javascript.

Comment: You know `location.hostname`, but you don’t know `location.port` …?

Comment: Yes, cause the port is not in the url... The URL is localhost, not localhost:5000. Heroku give me a port, I can't choose him but the url I enter is appname.herokuapp.com, I do not have port in window.location

Answer (score 0):

The $PORT is supplied by Heroku to your application running on Heroku as a way for it to bind for web traffic.  It's basically internal - a binding between your app in its dyno - and the routers.

Externally, your web app is available port 80, like most web apps are.